# Is smoothing an appropriate solution to deal with model diagnostics in a GAMLSS?

Tags: r, smoothing, gamlss

I have just recently started using GAMLSS models ([after being pointed in that direction in this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489040/dealing-with-heteroskedasticity-in-negative-binomial-glm/489152?noredirect=1#comment907156_489152)), and I'm wondering wether it's 'legit' to use smoothing (i.e. cubic splines in my case) to deal with unsatisfactory wormplots (I know how this sounds and this is why I'm posting this question to our community of stats geniuses).

I'm analyzing a harvest dataset and I'm trying to figure out which parameters influence hunting success and whether there's a diminishing trend in harvest in the past 20 years. My data is a daily number of birds harvested and I have co-variates that explain variation in daily harvest (effort: number of hours spent hunting; number of birds present on the reserve daily, proportion of young in the fall flight (yearly covariate)).

I'm using `gamlss` because of the multiple distributions that can be used for model fitting and because it allows me to model variance (sigma) in harvest according to some parameters (in my case effort and year - harvest varies less and less as years go by).

Here is an excerpt of the dataset:

```
   year   day   date       harvest inventory YAratio hours
   <dbl> <dbl> <date>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2000   276 2000-10-02      96     23000      26   76.5
2  2000   277 2000-10-03      95     21500      26   139. 
3  2000   278 2000-10-04     323     26000      26   143  
4  2000   279 2000-10-05     356     16500      26   135.
```

I did model selection to determine the distribution that fit my data best and went with the Poisson Inverse Gaussian distribution.

Here is the model I'm trying to fit:

```
gamlss(harvest ~ YAratio + inventory + offset(log(hours)) + random(factor(year)),
         sigma.formula = harvest ~ offset(log(hours))+random(factor(year)),
         data = dataframe, 
         family = PIG)
```

My problem is that I'm getting unsatisfactory wormplots from this model, particularly when looking at the inventory variable (which varies a lot, if that changes anything). Here is a wormplot obtained with the command

```
wp(mod, xvar=dataframe$inventory, n.inter=4)
```

[image]

A lot of the points fall out of the dotted lines (which, from what I could gather, means model violation for the section of the explanatory variable represented by the wormplot where the dots are over the lines). I figured smoothing might give the model more flexibility to deal with the inventory data and so I added a cubic spline term to the model like so:

```
gamlss(harvest ~ YAratio + cs(inventory, 3) + offset(log(hours)) + random(factor(year)),
         sigma.formula = harvest ~ offset(log(hours))+random(factor(year)),
         data = dataframe, 
         family = PIG)
```

Which yields the following wormplot (much better):

[image]

This model is also supported by GAIC (-12 points with the original model). My question is then: is this a legit way to deal with my wormplot problem? Model estimates are quite similar between the two models and predictions (CI obtained by simulating data from model estimates) from the latter model fit pretty well with the original data:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overall and predictor-specific worm plots share the feature that "different shapes indicate different inadequacies in the model", as explained in the article **Analysis of longitudinal multilevel experiments using GAMLSSs** by Gustavo Thomas et al: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.03085.pdf.

Section 12.4 of the book *Flexible Regression and Smoothing: Using GAMLSS in R*. by Rigby et al. is worth a read, as it provides a comprehensive tour of how to interpret worm plots. The section concludes with these statements: "In general, it may not always be possible to build a model without areas of misfits." and "In any case, extra care is needed when a model with many areas of misfits is used to support conclusions.". However, calibration is mentioned as one solution to be used in order to minimize misfits.

How you correct the model misfit depends on the nature of the problems detected in the worm plots.  If those problems suggest the need to consider nonlinear effects for one of your continuous predictor to improve model fit, than you would need to model the effect of that predictor nonlinearly rather than linearly. (Other types of corrections may involve specifying a different type of distribution for the response variable given the predictors and random effects in your model, omitting or including predictors from various parts of the model, transforming predictors, etc.)

Note that, according to the help file for the cs() function:

*The function scs() differs from the function cs() in that allows cross validation of the smoothing parameters unlike the cs() which fixes the effective degrees of freedom, df. Note that the recommended smoothing function is now the function pb() which allows the estimation of the smoothing parameters using a local maximum likelihood. The function pb() is based on the penalised beta splines (P-splines) of Eilers and Marx (1996).*

So you might want to consider using pb() in your model rather than cs().

**Addendum:**

Here is some R code for generating data for a model where a quadratic fit would work better than a linear or even a smooth fit.  It will help you build some intuition for what you can expect worm plots to look like. The data were generated according to https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-4/.

```
14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), 
Outcome = c(126.6, 101.8, 71.6, 101.6, 68.1, 62.9, 45.5, 41.9, 
46.3, 34.1, 38.2, 41.7, 24.7, 41.5, 36.6, 19.6, 
22.8, 29.6, 23.5, 15.3, 13.4, 26.8, 9.8, 18.8, 25.9, 19.3)), 
.Names = c("Time", "Outcome"),
row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L),
class = "data.frame")

Data
```

The header of the data looks like this:

````
  Time Outcome
1    0   126.6
2    1   101.8
3    2    71.6
5    4   101.6
7    6    68.1
9    8    62.9```

The plot of the Outcome variable versus the predictor variable Time can be obtained with:

```library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = Outcome)) + 
geom_point(size=3, colour="dodgerblue")
````

[image]

Now, fit the 3 possible models for these data within the gamlss framework:

```
linear.model <- gamlss(Outcome ~ Time, data = Data, family=NO)
quadratic.model <- gamlss(Outcome ~ Time + I(Time^2), data = Data, family=NO)
smooth.model <- gamlss(Outcome ~ pb(Time), data = Data, family=NO)

summary(linear.model)
summary(quadratic.model)
summary(smooth.model)
```

Compare the (generalized) AIC values of the 3 fitted models:

`GAIC(linear.model, quadratic.model, smooth.model)`

The quadratic model comes as the "winner" since it has the smallest AIC value:

```
                      df      AIC
quadratic.model 4.000000 197.0357
smooth.model    5.251898 197.8349
linear.model    3.000000 219.0893
```

Now construct the worm plots for the Time predictor:

```
wp(linear.model, xvar=Time)
wp(quadratic.model, xvar=Time)
wp(smooth.model, xvar=Time)
```

The worm plot for the linear model fit shows some misfit problems:
[image]

The worm plots for the quadratic and smooth model fits look a bit better than the worm plot for the linear model fit.

[image]

[image]

We can also plot the model residuals directly against the Time predictor:

```
Data$linear.model.residuals <- residuals(linear.model)
Data$quadratic.model.residuals <- residuals(quadratic.model)
Data$smooth.model.residuals <- residuals(smooth.model)

plot1 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = linear.model.residuals)) + 
         geom_point(size=3, colour="darkgrey") + 
         geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype=2, colour="red") + 
         ggtitle("Linear Model Residuals vs. Time") + 
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,3))


plot2 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = quadratic.model.residuals)) + 
         geom_point(size=3, colour="darkgrey") + 
         geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype=2, colour="red") +
         ggtitle("Quadratic Model Residuals vs. Time") + 
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,3))


plot3 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = smooth.model.residuals)) + 
         geom_point(size=3, colour="darkgrey") + 
         geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype=2, colour="red") +
         ggtitle("Smooth Model Residuals vs. Time") + 
         coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,3))

library(cowplot)

plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol=3)
```

[image]

These last plots make it a bit easier to discern that there is a quadratic pattern present in the residuals for the linear model, which needs to be accounted for in the model.

If you wanted to, you could pull apart the plot of residuals versus Time for the linear model and examine the portions of the plot corresponding to the division of Time in intervals used in the corresponding worm plot:

```
w.linear <- wp(linear.model, xvar=Time, main="Given: Time")
w.linear
```

The cutpoints for the division of the range of observed values of Time is reported in the $classes portion of the R output for w.linear:

```
> w.linear
$classes
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] -0.5  8.5
[2,]  8.5 15.5
[3,] 15.5 24.5
[4,] 24.5 30.5

$coef
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  0.6061177  0.79644473  0.26190049 -0.29589027
[2,] -1.0467772 -0.54040972  0.08504976 -0.05550396
[3,] -0.1400464 -0.64524770 -0.15331613  0.02095304
[4,]  0.7161490 -0.03070935 -0.08930395 -0.19956330
```

These cutpoints are -0.5, 8.5, 15.5, 24.5 and 30.5.  We can plot the residuals versus Time and draw vertical lines for only the "middle" cutpoints:

```
plot11 <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = linear.model.residuals)) + 
          geom_point(size=3, colour="darkgrey") + 
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype=2, colour="red") + 
          ggtitle("Linear Model Residuals vs. Time") + 
          coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,3)) + 
          geom_vline(xintercept = w.linear$classes[1,2], 
                 colour="blue", linetype=3, size=1.5) + 
      geom_vline(xintercept = w.linear$classes[2,2], 
                     colour="blue", linetype=3, size=1.5) +
          geom_vline(xintercept = w.linear$classes[3,2], 
                     colour="blue", linetype=3, size=1.5) 

plot11
```

This allows us to zoom in on specific time intervals and determine how the model fit breaks down in those intervals:

[image]

Comment: Wow that is very clear! I'll give that a go thanks so much!

Comment: You’re welcome, @Tilt! My mind likes for things to be clear - if they are not, it means I am not understanding things deeply enough. My own feeling is that plotting the model residuals from the model with just a linear effect for your relevant predictor against that predictor would be easier to interpret in your case. You would probably need to build separate residual vs predictor plots for each Year.  If you add your vector of residuals to your data, this subsetting by Year will be easier to do.

Comment: Yes you're right, it does show more clearly where/what the problem might be. I imagine the idea behind making a graph for each year would be to see if things go horribly wrong in a given year?

Answer (score 3):

A worm plot is basically a qq plot, so what you are doing is trying to find the best functional form of the covariates that yields a normal quantile Residual. This indicates a better fit.

You checked the information criterion, and you could also do a likelihood ratio test. But if the model has a better fit, there isn't anything wrong with cubic splines.

I would also advise you to check the residuals diagnostic using the plot function on the fitted gamlss object. This will give you another view, complementary to the worm plot.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer, Guilherme!  Would the likelihood ratio you suggested be implemented with the anova() function?